# The Mathematical Relationship Between Big-Oh Classes

Tags: algorithm, big-o, complexity-theory

My textbook describes the relationship as follows:

> There is a very nice mathematical intuition which describes these classes too. Suppose we have an algorithm which has running time N0 when given an input of size n, and a running time of N1 on an input of size 2n. We can characterize the rates of growth in terms of the relationship between N0 and N1:
>
> ```
> Big-Oh      Relationship
>
> O(log n)    N1 ≈ N0 + c
> O(n)        N1 ≈ 2N0
> O(n²)       N1 ≈ 4N0
> O(2ⁿ)       N1 ≈ (N0)²
> ```

Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically what they are trying to show is just basic algebra after substituting 2n for n in the functions.

```
O(log n)    
log(2n) = log(2) + log(n)
N1 ≈ c + N0

O(n)
2n = 2(n)        
N1 ≈ 2N0

O(n²)       
(2n)^2 = 4n^2 = 4(n^2)
N1 ≈ 4N0

O(2ⁿ)       
2^(2n) = 2^(n*2) = (2^n)^2
N1 ≈ (N0)²
```

Answer (score 2):

That is because if `f(n)` is in `O(g(n))` then it can be thought of as acting like `k * g(n)` for some `k`.

So for example if `f(n) = O(log(n))` then it acts like `k log(n)`, and now `f(2n) ≈ k log(2n) = k (log(2) + log(n)) = k log(2) + k log(n) ≈ k log(2) + f(n)` and that is your desired equation with `c = k log(2)`.

Note that this is a rough intuition **only**.  An example of where it breaks down is that `f(n) = (2 + sin(n)) log(n) = O(log(n))`.  The oscillating `2 + sin(n)` bit means that `f(2n)-f(n)` can be basically anything.

I personally find this kind of rough intuition to be misleading and therefore worse than useless.  Others find it very helpful.  Decide for yourself how much weight you give it.

Answer (score 1):

Since `O(f(n)) ~ k * f(n)` (almost by definition), you want to look at what happens when you put `2n` in for `n`. In each case:

`N1 ≈ k*log 2n = k*(log 2 + log n) = k*log n + k*log 2 ≈ N0 + c where c = k*log 2`

`N1 ≈ k*(2n) = 2*k*n ≈ 2N0`

`N1 ≈ k*(2n)^2 = 4*k*n^2 ≈ 4N0`

`N1 ≈ k*2^(2n) = k*(2^n)^2 ≈ N0*2^n ≈ N0^2/k`

So the last one is not quite right, anyway. Keep in mind that these relationships are only true asymptotically, so the approximations will be more accurate as `n` gets larger. Also, `f(n) = O(g(n))` only means `g(n)` is an upper bound for `f(n)` for large enough `n`. So `f(n) = O(g(n))` does not necessarily mean `f(n) ~ k*g(n)`. Ideally, you want that to be true, since your `big-O` bound will be tight when that is the case.